# SQLAlchemy not working with integrated gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I have a Flask application that uses SQLAlchemy.

When I run the app with:

```
gunicorn --workers 6 -k gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -m 007 wsgi:app
```

Everything is working fine.

**However, when I try to integrate it with gunicorn app:**

```py
# start_app.py

from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication
import gunicorn
from gunicorn import glogging
from gunicorn.workers import sync, ggevent
import wsgi


class StandaloneApplication(BaseApplication):

    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


def main_function():
    options = {
            'bind': '0.0.0.0:5000',
            'workers': 6,
            'worker_class': 'gevent',
            'umask': 0x07
    }
    StandaloneApplication(wsgi.app, options).run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
```

And run it as: `python start_app.py`.

I am suddenly getting many strange `SQLAlchemy` exceptions. For example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/tmp/Temp/server/routes.py", line 27, in alarms
    result = db_utils.build_alarms_response(session)
  File "/tmp/Temp/server/db_utils.py", line 129, in build_alarms_response
    system_alarms = get_alarms_per_system(session, no_id)
  File "/tmp/Temp/server/db_utils.py", line 115, in get_alarms_per_system
    alarms = db_models.get_alarms(session)
  File "/tmp/Temp/server/db_models.py", line 405, in get_alarms
    return session.query(Alarms).options(options).all()
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2759, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2897, in _iter
    execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1691, in execute
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1533, in _connection_for_bind
    engine, execution_options
  File "/tmp/Temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 754, in _connection_for_bind
    if self.session.twophase and self._parent is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'twophase'
```

As anyone encountered this kind of issue before?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768428/sqlalchemy-connection-errors) is old, but suggests the exception may be raised if concurrent connections are not being managed properly.  How are you managing your sessions?

Comment: This is indeed a good hint. Although the problem only happens with integrated `gunicorn` standalone application, and not with direct `gunicorn wsgi` run. It sounds now very possible that the `gunicorn` integration affects concurrency, causing the problem to surface.

Comment: After checking, unfortunately, the error occurs even with a single worker.